See followed by an infintive and gerund

Everyone has seen plants __________.

a. grow
b. to grow
c. growing
d. to growing
Which is the correct answer and why?

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59193/see-noun-adjective-or-see-noun-verb https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158396/phrasal-verb-see-to-conflicting-with-passive-voice https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/300191/what-other-forms-of-verb-can-i-use-in-i-see-him-swelling-with-pride
